# Función dentro de un echo <<<

Tags: php, html

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
echo <<<HTML
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th><th>Carácter</th><th>Cód. URL</th>
    </tr>
HTML;

for ($i = 0; $i <= 255; $i++){
    echo <<<HTML
        <tr>
            <td>$i</td><td>chr($i)</td><td>urlencode(chr($i))</td>
        </tr>
    HTML;
}

echo "</table>";
```

Básicamente estoy intentando que las funciones `chr()` y `urlencode()` funcionen dentro del string del `echo` `heredoc`.
¿Hay alguna forma de poder utilizarlas en este tipo de `echo` sin tener que hacer algo como lo siguiente? (O si hay manera de hacer esto pero en el anterior `heredoc`)

```
echo "<tr>
          <td>$i</td><td>" . chr($i) . "</td><td>" . urlencode(chr($i)) . "</td>
      </tr>";
```

Más que nada por si toca hacer algo un poco más largo que esto, saber cómo manejar una función dentro.

Muchas gracias!

**EDITO:**

Añadí a una variable los resultados y los concatené dentro del `string` del [`heredoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) (averigué el nombre)
Este sería el resultado dentro del bucle `for`.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 255; $i++){
        $caracter = chr($i);
        $codigo = urlencode(chr($i));
        
        echo <<<HTML
            <tr>
                <td>$i</td><td>$caracter</td><td>$codigo</td>
            </tr>
        HTML;
    }
```

Sigo abierto a nuevas maneras de hacerlo. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: has intentado concatenar ?

Comment: Buenas tardes!
Si, como puedes ver en mi comentario, concatenando no hay ningún problema.
Mi duda es si hay manera de "concatenar" en el echo<<< (que no sé como se llama) o de incluir funciones de la misma forma que se pueden incluir variables, por ejemplo (como estoy incluyendo $i.
Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: si y no en teoría primero haces la concatenación en una variables y después el ouput...

Comment: Entonces, si no he entendido mal sugieres algo como almacenar el resultado de la funcion en una variable y meter esa variable en el echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con una variable de buffer y después mostrarlo con `Heredoc`:

```
<?php

$buffer = '<table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th><th>Carácter</th><th>Cód. URL</th>
                </tr>';
                
for ($i = 0; $i <= 255; $i++){
    $buffer .= '<tr>
                    <td>'.$i.'</td><td>'.chr($i).'</td><td>'.urlencode(chr($i)).'</td>
                </tr>';
}

$buffer .= '</table>';

echo <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: consolas">
        $buffer
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

?>
```